# Java Batch Transaction processing - DB lookup cache

Tags: java, database, caching

I have a batch processing application run on java, which processes the incoming text file, validates it and stores the records to DB.
As part of validation the batch process checks if the record exists in a particular table in DB.If does not exist it skips the input record and processes next record.

The input record batch file contains millions of records and table also contains millions of records. So the validation process runs for long time to validate each of the record's existence in DB.
I am looking for a solution to simplify this with caching or any other possible solution.

since caching millions of records in memory will be a overhead, is there any other solution to cache the records without affecting performance?

Are there any better caching framework that can resolve this problem?

Core java with Plain JDBC code is used, no hibernate or other frameworks. Database is oracle.

Comment: Cant you just create a foreign key relationship between the  table you are inserting into and the column that you are checking? Try and insert and catch the RI exception if it fails.

Comment: This will end up in trying to insert every record to DB and huge number of exceptions. Aim is to reduce db hits. Just ignore the records that are invalid.